# Store a list of .rb files inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

colleagues! I have Document model. Document should be processed by one of the parsers (in my project they are called 'importers' and stored inside 'lib/importers' folder). The question is about what is the best way to implement entity Importer inside models layer? (for instance associate document with importer).

1. First idea is to create importers table, but then I will have 2 independent places where importer names will be saved (database and file system). Bad cases:

**Case 1:** I've aded a new importer, but forgot to add it to importers table = I can't associate document with this impoter

**Case 2:** Importer was renamed and we forgot to rename it inside database = error

2. I decided to define

   `def Document.importers
     @importers ||= Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/lib/importers/")
            .select { |name| !File.directory?(name) && name != 'base_importer.rb'}
            .map { |name| name.gsub(/\.rb$/, '') }
   end`

for f.association inout and add importer string attribute to the document model. So I can get importer class in following way -- 'importer.classify.constantize'. It works, but it looks creepy

Can you advice better solution for this situation? I will appreciate to hear any ideas ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solvation made during brain storm in my local ruby chat:

I haven't mentioned that all importers are inherited from the base_importer which is also placed in lib/importers. We decided to add 'inheritors' array to it and store all inheritors there using hook 'inherited' provided by the ruby core -> http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited.

```
class BaseImporter
  @inheritors = []

  def self.inheritors
    @inheritors
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    @inheritors << subclass.name
  end
  # ...
end
```

We expected it to work well, but we forgot, that all classes are eager loaded in Rails. So BaseImporter.inheritors will return [] to you on the fresh system start.:

```
anton@anton:~/Projects/project$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 16832
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
B2.2.3 :001 > BaseImporter.inheritors
 => []
```

To force loading of all importers I made an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/importers.rb
# Preload importers
require 'base_importer'
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/importers/*.rb").each { |file| require file }
```

BaseImporter should be loaded first, because if any importer will be loaded before BaseImporter it will not fire 'inherited' hook:

```
anton@anton:~/Projects/project$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 16846
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.2.3 :001 > require "xxx_importer"
 => true 
2.2.3 :002 > require "base_importer"
 => true 
2.2.3 :003 > require "yyy_importer"
 => true 
2.2.3 :004 > BaseImporter.inheritors
 => ["XxxImporter"]
```

**Feel free to post your feedback on this solution. I will be glad to hear it**

Answer (score 0):

I would model them in the database, and then have some system in place to update the database if the files change.  This happens all the time with asset management systems: you have some physical files, and some data, and yes, if they go out of sync you've got problems.  So, you put systems in place to try to keep them in sync.  You can have a rake task to update the database based on the physical files for example, then the protocol is that you need to run the rake task after changing the files, and if you don't then you screwed up and the problems are your fault.  Developers should be able to work within these sorts of rules.

Ultimately, Rails is about object-relational data, so work with that if you want to use rails.  If you try to go down some route of building a load of instances on the fly every time, based on the contents of the folder, then you will just end up with a very complicated and inefficient system.

Comment: Thank you for your response Max! I don't think rake task is the best solvation, because I am sure that I need to use some kind of automatic way. Maybe, you meant some kind of automation, that hooks rake task every time importer has changed, but I don't know how to hook any kind of scripts when files in specific directory is changed. I will post solution from my local ruby chat here. Feel free to criticize it if you see any weak moments in it